# yuv to jpeg iOS

Tags: ios, image

I want to convert a yuv 420SP image (captured directly from camera, YCbCr format) to jpg in iOS. What I have found is CGImageCreate() function https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000956-CH1g-F17167 , which takes in a few parameters including the byte array containing and should return some CGImage, whose UIImage when input to UIImageJPEGRepresentation() returns jpeg data, but that is not really happening
The output image data is far from what is required. At least the output is not nil.

As input to CGImageCreate(), bits per component i am setting as 4, bits per pixel as 12, and some default values.

Can it really convert a yuv YCbCr image ad not only rgb? If yes, then i think i am doing wrong something in the input values to the CGImageCreate function.

Comment: Looking for same thing. Any luck with this?

Comment: No luck. The result that I have is this:
The default encoder, i.e., `CGImageCreate()` can only be used to convert from RGBA (interleaved, quartz doesn't support planar) formatted image to JPEG. I read somewhere in the documentation, it had a table with all possible values for the bits per pixel, bits per component etc. All of them (probably, as i don't remember properly) corresponded to RGBA. None corresponded to yuv, of that I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGColorSpace/Reference/reference.html), the `CGColorSpaceRef colorspace` parameter can refer to RGB, CMYK, or grayscale only.

So I think first you need to convert your YCbCr420 image to RGB, for example, using IPP function `YCbCr420toRGB` ([doc](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/ipp/ippi/ippi_ch6/functn_YCbCr420ToRGB.html#functn_YCbCr420ToRGB)). Alternatively, you can write your own conversion routine, it's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for converting a sample buffer returned by the `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection` method of `AVVideoDataOutput`:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
    GLubyte *rawImageBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer); //2560 == (640 * 4)
    size_t bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
    size_t bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);  //480
    size_t dataSize = CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(pixelBuffer); //1_228_808 = (2560 * 480) + 8
CGColorSpaceRef defaultRGBColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();


    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawImageBytes, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, 8, bytesPerRow, defaultRGBColorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    CFMutableDataRef imageData = CFDataCreateMutable(NULL, 0);
    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(imageData, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, NULL);
    NSDictionary *properties = @{(__bridge id)kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality: @(0.25),
                                 (__bridge id)kCGImageDestinationBackgroundColor: (__bridge id)CLEAR_COLOR,
                                 (__bridge id)kCGImageDestinationOptimizeColorForSharing : @(TRUE)
                                 };
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)properties);

    if (!CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination))
    {
        CFRelease(imageData);
        imageData = NULL;
    }
    CFRelease(destination);

    UIImage *frame = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image];
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGImageRelease(image);

    renderFrame([self.childViewControllers.lastObject.view viewWithTag:1].layer, frame);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
}
```

Here are your three options for pixel format types:

```
kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange
kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange
kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA
```

If `_captureOutput` is the pointer reference to my instance of `AVVideoDataOutput`, this is how you set the pixel format type:

```
[_captureOutput setVideoSettings:@{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)}];
```